# perl regex matched part as output filename

Tags: perl, awk

when I have a simple file like

```
Ann Math 99
Bob Math 100
Ann Chemistry 92
Ann History 78
```

I may split it into files per person with

```
awk '{print > $1}' input_filename
```

However, when the file becomes complex, it is no longer possible to do so unless I use a very complex regex as a field separator. I find that I can extract output filename with some regex, and the following command seems to be able to do what I want for a test with 5 lines:

```
sed 5q input_filename | perl -nle 'if(/\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]/){open(FH,">","$1"); print FH $_; close FH}'
```

but the file is large and the command seems to be inefficient. Are there better ways to do it?

---

original files are like this:

```
SOME_VERY_LONG_STUFF[TAG1]SOME_EVEN_LONGER_STUFF
SOME_VERY_LONG_STUFF[TAG2]SOME_EVEN_LONGER_STUFF
SOME_VERY_LONG_STUFF[TAG3]SOME_EVEN_LONGER_STUFF
SOME_VERY_LONG_STUFF[TAG1]SOME_EVEN_LONGER_STUFF
SOME_VERY_LONG_STUFF[TAG3]SOME_EVEN_LONGER_STUFF
...
```

and I just want to split it into files with name TAG1, TAG2, TAG3..., each file contains and only contains lines in the original file that has the tag in the bracket.

the first line with small modifications:

```
Nov 30 18:00:00 something@syslog: [2019-11-30 18:00:00][BattleEnd],{"result":1,"life":[[0,30,30],[1,30,30],[2,30,29],[3,30,29],[4,30,29],[5,28,29],[6,28,21],[7,28,21],[8,28,14],[9,28,14],[10,29,13],[11,21,13],[12,21,13],[13,15,13],[14,16,12],[15,12,12],[16,12,12],[17,9,12],[18,9,12],[19,5,12],[20,5,12],[21,3,12],[22,3,12],[23,1,12],[24,1,10],[25,1,10],[26,1,10],[27,1,10],[28,2,9],[29,-1,9]],"Info":[[160,0],[161,0],[162,0],[163,0],[155,0],[157,0],[158,0],[159,0]],"cards":[11401,11409,11408,12201,12208,10706,12002,10702,12207,12204,12001,12007,12208,10702,12005,10701,12005,11404,10705,10705,12007,11401,10706,12002,12001,12204,10701,12207,11404,11409,11408,12201]}
```

the tag I want is "BattleEnd". I want to split the log according to log sources.

Comment: Could you please mention it clearly like what output should output file have? And what should be output file names?

Comment: Also since you are talking about complex regex, so could you please do show samples for your Input_file's 1st field so that we could help in writing regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed samples so adding this code now, completely based on shown samples of OP.

```
awk -F"[][]" '{print >> ($4);close($4)}' Input_file
```

OR if you want to `close` output files(to avoid `too many files opened error`) on whenever previous field is NOT matched then try following.

```
awk -F"[][]" 'prev!=$4{close(prev)} {print >> ($4);prev=$4}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples.

```
awk '
match($0,/[^]]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*\[/,"",val)
  print >> (val)
  close(val)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Such a simple and elegant delimiter! Thanks! Besides, is  '{print >> ($4); close($4)}' better than '{print > $4}'? I've always been using the latter.